# Configure Wireshark to capture any packages between host machine, and guest (VM)

Tags: http, wireshark, tcp

I'm new to this whole **Wireshark** thing. I have a VM running inside my local Mac via **VMWare Fusion**.

- **VM** IP Address : 172.16.139.129
- **Mac** IP Address : 10.0.0.4

I want to capture `http` connection between my VM and Mac. 
What should I set/configure to see those packages ?

Here is what I'm selecting right now as my interfaces.

[image]

---

**Network Adapter**

I have 2 network adapters, 1st one set to `Host-Only`, and 2nd one set `NAT`

[image]

---

**Result**

I don't see any packages that related to that IP at all. 
I've tried adding port : `1234` to my tcp port list also. 
Result still the same. I only see other packages.

---

On my Mac, on a browser when I go to : `http://172.16.139.129:1234/vse/accounts` , I got

[image]

**Any hints / suggestions on this will be much appreciated !**

Comment: How does port 1234 come into it?  Wireshark should capture everything.  Try running ifconfig (or the Mac equivalent) on both machines to validate the IP addresses.  Also, are you running Wireshark on the host or guest?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the NAT adapter is your default route. If so, you won't ever see the IP address of the machine since it's NAT'ed and the router (I.e. your computer) will masquerade with its own IP address. In that case, look for traffic coming from your computer's address.

Alternatively, to give the VM it's own real IP address, switch to bridged networking.

If you're still having issues, you should show what Wirrshark filters you are trying to use.